# opcache.memory_consumption configuration

Tags: php, opcache, php-8

What will happen if I set higher value for a function in `php.ini`, For example set 2GB to `opcache.memory_consumption` for a normal e-commerce web application.

```
opcache.memory_consumption = 2048
```

Below is my pod resource configuration

```
 resources:
        limits:
          cpu: "1"
          memory: "1Gi"
        requests:
          cpu: "450m"
          memory: "256Mi"
```

If I set 2GB for OPcache itself. What will happen if it's exceed actual memory limit of the application.

Comment: Please share more details. Why not try it out and see what happens? I would assume that your application would still work

Comment: @NicoHaase Application works fine. But Kubernetes pod memory request is very high compared to previous versions without OPcache

Comment: @GaPa Yes, OpCache persists things in memory, so turning it on may well use more memory than turning it off. Incidentally, OpCache is not new in PHP 8.0, it's been included since 5.5, eight years ago, so this isn't about "previous versions", unless you've upgraded some _really_ old code.

Comment: I'm running PHP inside a k8s pod and It's reading the whole node's memory. Not my tiny pod: `Used memory 24055976`, `Free memory 110161752`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/opcache.configuration.php#ini.opcache.memory-consumption):

> opcache.memory_consumption int
>
> The size of the shared memory storage used by OPcache, in megabytes. The minimum permissible value is "8", which is enforced if a smaller value is set.

OK, so what is the shared memory storage used for, and why might we want more of it? As it happens, Nikita Popov, one of the most important developers of PHP's internals right now, just wrote a blog post about [how opcache works](https://www.npopov.com/2021/10/13/How-opcache-works.html). Before going into details of how, he summarises thus:

> The primary purposes of opcache is to cache compilation artifacts in shared memory, to avoid the need to recompile PHP scripts on every execution.

So, the memory is used to cache the result of compiling your PHP code to an intermediate representation used internally. The amount of space needed will depend on how much compiled code you're trying to cache at once.

How do we know if it's enough? By running [the opcache_get_status() function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.opcache-get-status.php). If the memory is full, or very nearly full, there's a chance that some of your scripts aren't getting cached because they don't fit in memory. In that case, increasing the configured memory size will improve performance by caching those files.

If the memory already has plenty of space, then increasing the size further won't make any difference, other than preventing the server using that memory for other things.

Comment: Is it something to do with actual memory consumption ? Say for example in the Kubernetes pods memory request

Comment: @GaPa I'm sorry, I have no idea what you mean by "actual memory consumption" or "memory request". It is an amount of memory, reserved for a particular use. If you set it higher, more memory will be reserved.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have edited question a bit. If I have some configuration that exceeds actual memory what will happen? Application is still working not sure whether I can set some value higher than actual pod configuration or not.

Comment: @GaPa Most likely, OpCache will try to allocate the requested amount, fail, and switch itself off. It certainly can't invent memory that doesn't exist.